# Jquery - Array value split by comma - Parsing error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to split values by comma.

But, One of my JSON returns value like below as per requirement. within value, text has comma.. Not sure how to remove comma and combine together.

```js
var str = "South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands,Congo, Democratic Republic,Mauritania,Finland";
var res = str.split(/(?<=\w),(?=\w)/i);
console.log(res)
```

Here it works as expected.

But, when i run this syntax in gulp package.. getting

**Parsing error: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=\w),(?=\w)/: Invalid group**

Please let me know whether is there any syntax can use? I cant able to use split(',') for our requirement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative lookbehind is not supported in all environments. Here, you can use word boundaries instead, which will match the position between `\w\W` or `\W\w`. (A comma is `\W` - it's not a word character)

```js
var str = "South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands,Congo, Democratic Republic,Mauritania,Finland";
var res = str.split(/\b,\b/i);
console.log(res)
```

Another (uglier) option would be to match a word character, followed by any characters, followed by another word character, until lookahead matches `,\w` or the end of the string:

```js
var str = "South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands,Congo, Democratic Republic,Mauritania,Finland";
var res = str.match(/\w.*?\w(?=,\w|$)/g);
console.log(res)
```